Cannot open geotiffs downloaded with rvest
I am trying to download ~200 geotiffs from NOAA into R using package 'rvest'.
The website with the data is here (https://noaadata.apps.nsidc.org/NOAA/).

NOAA provides instructions on how to bulk download the geotiff data here (https://nsidc.org/data/user-resources/help-center/how-access-and-download-noaansidc-data), at the bottom of the page under 'Download a Directory'
    library(rvest)

    setwd("path-to-my-directory")

    url <- "https://noaadata.apps.nsidc.org/NOAA/G02135/south/daily/geotiff/2023/05_May"

    page <- read_html(url)

    files <- page %>% 
         html_nodes("a") %>%
         html_attr("href")

    for(i in 2:length(files)){  
    u <- paste(url,files[i], sep="/")  
    download.file(u,files[i], mode = "wb")


When I run the code (using my working directory) it does download all the geotiffs. However, when I try to open them using the 'raster' package, I get this error
    file <- raster("path-to-file.geotiff")


I know that something is going wrong in the bulk download step using rvest, because if I instead download a geotiff from the NOAA website by clicking on it, I can open it as a raster in R without issue.
I have looked at the help docs for the rvest functions and have been unable to find a solution.

Please do not add code as images for these reasons. Instead, add code in codeblocks e.g three backticks "````" (without the quotes), then add code on a new line, then three backticks on a new line after the code.

The URL you show in code view-source:https://noaadata.apps.nsidc.org/NOAA/G02135/south/daily/geotiff/2023/05_May/ doesn't seem to to contain any files that end in geotiff, just tif. The error seems to be coming from raster which doesn't know how to open that file format. I'm not sure rvest is the problem here. Maybe the files just need to be renamed to just have a "tif" extension

As MrFlick mentioned the file extension is just tif, not geotiff. To reduce the chance of this error in the future, you can skip the process of directly downloading the data and allow the raster package do it for you.
library(rvest)
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp


url <- "https://noaadata.apps.nsidc.org/NOAA/G02135/south/daily/geotiff/2023/05_May"

page <- read_html(url)

files <- page %>% 
        html_nodes("a") %>%
        html_attr("href")

rasters <- paste0(url, "/", files[2]) %>%
    lapply(raster)

Created on 2024-06-25 with reprex v2.1.0
